# Jquery созданный класс

Tags: jquery

Есть блок, к которому класс добавляется программно,
то есть:

```
<div class="form"> // класс form добавляется с помощью jquery
<form class="our_form"....
...../form>
</div>
```

Но почему-то код, что добавляю, не работает. (

```
$('document').on( 'submit', '.form form.our_form', function (){
alert("123");
});
```

---

Этот код не работает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё работает отлично: http://jsfiddle.net/8m7w86f9/

Ещё иногда можно идти таким путём: http://jsfiddle.net/8m7w86f9/3/

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.hasClass('myform')) { return true; }

    // custom action

    alert('submit');
    return false;
});
```